# Increment value with eventListener

Tags: reactjs

Given:

```
export default function ComponentA(props) {

    const [x, setX] = useState(0)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        connect("http://localhost:18200/events/agg/dotusd");
    })

    const connect = (url) => {
        const es = new EventSource(url, { withCredentials: false });
        es.addEventListener('heartBeat', handleHeartBeat);
    };

    const handleHeartBeat = (event) => {
        setX((x) => x + 1)
        const currentdate = new Date(); 
        const datetime = " "
                + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                + currentdate.getSeconds();
        console.log("time =", datetime + "; x =", x)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <ComponentB key='1' x={x} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

When: `heartbeat` event occurs.

Then: increment `x` value and log it to the console, so:

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
...
```

Result: it makes a strange recursion:

```
0  
0 1  
0 1 2  
0 1 2 3  
...
```

Why and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: You never disconnect from your event source, which could lead to memory leaks and other bad things, like hitting the maximum number of connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an empty array as the second argument to `useEffect`.  This tells react to only run that code once, when the component mounts.  Currently, every time this component re-renders, its adding another event listener.

```
useEffect(() => {
    connect("http://localhost:18200/events/agg/dotusd");
}, [])
```